# How to update my working Git branch from another branch (develop)?

Tags: git, github, branch, git-merge

I made a new branch called `feature1` from the main `develop` branch a month ago.

```
⇒  git branch 
  develop
* feature1
```

I've been working on `feature1` for a month now and a lot of changes have been pushed to `develop`.

How can I update my current branch `feature1` with the latest commits from `develop`?

I DO NOT want to checkout `master` and merge my `feature1` branch into it. Neither do I want to use `git cherry-pick` to manually move commits from `develop` to `feature1`.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

You just merge develop to feature1:

```
git checkout feature1
git merge develop
```

There is no need to involve another branch such as master.

Comment: But this will place all commits of develop into the branch

Comment: Of course it will. The question essentially was "how can I place all commits of develop into the branch".

Comment: No , it's not,  it was "i am working in branch X, but i want that branch to have the latest updates from develop",  when you do a PR to develop you wish only to have your branch commits and not all history of commits

Comment: I don't understand. This has nothing to do with PRs. The current state of "develop" is supposed to end up in "feature1". A merge as described accomplishes that.

Comment: Yes it has all to do. If the developer is alone or in a small team maybe nobody cares. But if he wants to merge this to develop in a team that has to review the branch, then they will see that all the develop commits were done instead of only showing the real changes introduced in the feature branch.

Comment: I mean. the current state of "develop" will be in "feature1", but the commits were not generated there. With the merge it will appear as if all those develop commits were generated in "feature1"

Comment: I don't think OP's question is about setting up a PR. It's about updating a personal dev branch to be based on the latest changes in the develop branch. Depending on what process you use to set up PRs, you should easily be able to specify exactly what commits you want reviewed (e.g., most recent commit only; or all commits on feature1 not in develop; etc.)

Anyway, once the merge is completed, feature1 and develop are definitely going to share commit history. It's not relevant which branch the developer was working in at the moment in the past when they committed onto develop.

Comment: Sorry, I think I did a poor job explaining. Let me try again... after the dev runs `git merge develop`, the tip of feature1 will be updated, including new code from develop. This lets the dev work with up-to-date code. The merge does not affect the develop branch in any way. Maybe at some point in the future, this dev will want to merge feature1 into develop (i.e. other way around) to update tip of develop and this requires review. At that point, whatever temporary merge commit(s) produced will be specified in the review so that reviewers can see the diff of how develop will change.

Comment: Hi folks, thanks for the above info and I need a little help with this:
I now have the latest changes from 'Develop' in my branch 'feature1' in my local machine. I want my branch 'feature1' on GITHUB to have the latest updates from 'develop' as well. How can I do this?

Comment: Well, just figured out, github was updated(synced) too, after I merged 'develop' into my branch 'feature1' . Cheers.

Answer (score 118):

First you need to update your **develop** branch, then checkout your **feature** and merge/rebase it.

```
git checkout develop
git pull
git checkout feature/myfeature
```

Now you can **decide** between running:

```
git merge develop
git rebase develop
```

- *`merge`:* keeps all commits history from your branch, and that is important if your partial commits have a lot of content that can be interesting to keep.
- *`rebase`:* Rebase means deleting the commit history from `feature` and instead have the history from `develop` or best said "reapplied" on top of the freshly pulled develop, just as if they were made on top of the fresh develop from the start.  this option is obligatory in some teams.

When you are ready you can push to your own branch (for example for a pull request)

```
git push origin feature/myfeature
```

Comment: I think this is a better solution than the designated answer.

Comment: `Rebase` means deleting the commit history from `feature` and instead have the history from `develop`

Comment: When you write "delete the commit history from feature", it sounds like those commits in feature are gone, which is not the case, they will be "reapplied" on top of the freshly pulled develop, just as if they were made on top of the fresh develop from the start.

Answer (score 7):

This use case is very helpful to keep updated your PR branch. Firstly, I would recommend you to fetch first your remote changes, i.e. `git fetch`
and then merge or rebase from `develop`, but from the remote one, e.g.

```
git rebase -i origin/develop
```

or

```
git merge origin/develop
```

This way you will update your PR branch without going back and forth between branches.

Comment: git rebase is like merge, isn't it?. but same thing happens,

Comment: In the git rebase your rewrite the history of your branch with a mix of the 2, with the merge you just apply the changes of the other branch into yours in a new merge-commit.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want that the `develop` head and the `feature1` head will merge both into `feature1`, but instead you want keeping each branch head distinct while "updating" `feature1` branch with the latest edit from `develop`, use **no fast-forward**:

```
git pull
git co feature1
git pull
git merge --no-ff develop
git push
```

I personally try to use `--no-ff` everytime I perform a merge because in my opinion it keeps the history quite clean.

Answer (score 0):

BRANCHS:

DEV         ====> develop

feature1    ====> working

---

**STEP 1**
GIT SENDING FROM THE SITE

checks the branch you're syncing

```
git status
```

add files for the commit

```
git add .
```

commits with a description

```
git commit -m "COMMENT"
```

send to the branch that you are synchronized

```
git push
```

---

**STEP 2**
SYNCHRONIZING THE UPDATED WORK BRANCH WITH DEV (development) - 
synchronizes the working branch with the development branch (updates the development branch)

synchronize with the remote and switch to the DEV branch

```
git checkout DEV
```

request to merge the branch that you are syncing with the feature1 branch

```
git merge feature1
```

Merge the current branch with the feature1 branch

```
git push
```

---

**STEP 3**
GIT FINDING THE REMOTE - Update the working branch from the updated development branch

connects to the reference branch

```
git checkout DEV
```

Search changes

```
git pull
```

Syncs with your work branch

```
git checkout feature1
```

request to merge the branch that you are synchronized with the DEV branch

```
git merge DEV
```

Merge the current branch with the DEV branch

```
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having the commits from develop by using a simple merge, i've found that the easier (less *techier*) way to do it is **specially if you already pushed**:

1. Change to develop and be sure you pulled latest changes
2. Create another branch from develop , `feature1_b`
3. Merge `feature1` to `feature1_b`
4. Delete if you wish original `feature1`

So when you do your PR of `feature1_b` into develop, it will only have your new changes and not the whole history of commits.

If you haven't pushed then @stackdave's answer is a good answer.

Comment: I really like this thinking. Especially that you can keep feature1 for as long as it might be needed, and that all critial screwups are in features rather than a more important branch.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Checkout the previous branch and pull the new branch
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71306254/17779236

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31194913)

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ IDEA just follow these steps:

1. open the Git Tool Window  (View->Tool Windows->Git)
   [image]
2. select "Log"

   [image]
3. right click on "develop"
4. click on either

   -Merge 'develop' onto 'feature1' (keeps all commits history from your branch)

   or

   -Rebase 'develop' into 'feature1' (delets the commit history from your branch and instead have the history from develop)

   [image]
5. Finally Git push

Answer (score -1):

```
$ git checkout <another-branch> <path-to-file> [<one-more-file> ...]
$ git status
$ git commit -m "Merged file from another branch"
```