# Update github branch from another branch

Tags: github, version-control, updates, git-merge, git-branch

I have created a branch from another branch. Then I come back to previous branch and work on it. Now I have switched to second branch. But this second branch don't have the new changes of first branch. I just want to update the second branch from first branch without deleting any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But this second branch don't have the new changes of first branch

Switching to the second branch alone is not enough for said branch to reflect changes committed in the first branch.

You would need to `git merge branch1` or, if you are the only one working on `branch2`: `git rebase branch1` (if you want to keep a  linear history).

Then, and only then, would you see `branch1` changes in `branch2`.

⇒ The [OP Waqar Ahmed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17779236/waqar-ahmed) proposes in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71304694/update-github-branch-from-another-branch/71306254#comment126043584_71306254):

> I have solved this issue but checking out `branch2` and pull the `branch1`

Comment: I have solved this issue but checking out branch2 and pull the branch1

Comment: @WaqarAhmed Well done. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.